# Memory issue when requesting for Gallery image DATA using Photos Framework in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, exif, photosframework

I am working on an iOS app in which I have to fetch all the images from **iPhone gallery** and then fetch its **exif Value**.To get exif value I need to get image using **image data**.

I am using following code for this:

```
-(void)getExifDataFromImage:(NSInteger)index{
PHImageRequestOptions *options = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
options.synchronous=YES;
options.resizeMode=PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeFast;

[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageDataForAsset:asset
                                                  options:options
                                            resultHandler:^(NSData *imageData, NSString *dataUTI, UIImageOrientation orientation, NSDictionary *info)
 {

     CIImage* ciImage = [CIImage imageWithData:imageData];
     NSLog(@"Metadata : %@", ciImage.properties);

     exifCount++;

     NSDictionary *pro=ciImage.properties;
     NSDictionary *exifDic=[pro objectForKey:@"{Exif}"];
     NSDictionary *tiffDic=[pro objectForKey:@"{TIFF}"];

}];}
```

All works fine for the images around **1200** but if we go beyond that we get **memory issue** and the application crashes.

I also tried getting image using the below code to get the image and then tried to find the exif value of the **resized image**.

```
 [self.imageManager requestImageForAsset:asset targetSize:CGSizeMake(360, 360) contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill options:nil resultHandler:^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary *info)
     {
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
             [self doSomething]
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                 imageView.image=result;
             });//
         });
     }];
```

But I am unable to get the exif value for the resized images.

**Error : libBacktraceRecording.dylib:  allocate_free_list_pages() -- virtual memory exhausted!**

Please suggest me how to handle this Memory crash issue. Also please suggest if there is another way to get the exif value.

Comment: Where are you calling your method `getExifDataFromImage:`?

Comment: @orkoden I am calling it in a loop to get the meta data of all the images. For 1000 to 1500 it works fine and then it crashes because of memory issue. Can you tell me how to get Image metadata (exif) for all possible images in the Camera Roll avoiding the crash .

Comment: You have to do it in batches of maybe 50 images at once, not all at once.

Answer (score 0):

You're loading autoreleased images with `CIImage* ciImage = [CIImage imageWithData:imageData];`. That will use up a lot of data really quickly because the Autorealeasepool is not drained.

You can wrap the image creation and dictionary access in `@autoreleasepool{/* your code*/}`. Or just use `CIImage* ciImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];` to let ARC take care of of freeing the memory.